# Retrieving ArrayList.get randomly using JSP object in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, arraylist

So I have an arraylist containing my data to display within my jsp file. I am trying to display this data in a table; however I want to grab items from the arraylist at a random index. This is done with r, yet I cannot simply type r rather than 5 when executing the following command.

```
"<%=allData.get(5).getRow_position()%>";
```

Hence how can I call this randomly when I can't use r as a parameter concatenate the string to get the string to add to my table? Thanks!

Code:

```
function updateDisplay(numIterate){
var table = document.getElementById("infoTable");
var startingRow = 1;

for(var i = 0; i < numIterate; i++){

var row = table.insertRow(startingRow);

var max = <%=allData.size()%>;
var min = 1;
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min))+min;

var rowPosition = row.insertCell(0);
var headline = row.insertCell(1);
var agency = row.insertCell(2); 
var dateEntered = row.insertCell(3);
var enteredBy = row.insertCell(4);

rowPosition.innerHTML = "<%=allData.get(5).getRow_position()%>";
headline.innerHTML = "<%=allData.get(5).getHeadline()%>";
agency.innerHTML = "<%=allData.get(5).getAgency()%>";
dateEntered.innerHTML = "
<%=allData.get(5).getDateEntered()%>".substring(0,10);
enteredBy.innerHTML = "<%=allData.get(5).getEnteredBy()%>";
startingRow+=1;
}
```

Comment: JSP = Java _Server_ Pages, it gets executed server side, not client side; Look into AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this -

```
//on Top 
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
//Also before you use rand and put max and min value
<%Random rand;
int r = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min; %>
//Replace 5 with r in your code
```

Comment: No luck. The problem is that I can't just make it a string. I need to use the var r, but there is no way that I know of to use it as a parameter because the statement is encapsulated in the expression tag.